# Using CSVParser to parse a tab-delimited file

Tags: java, xml, csv

I need to parse a file which is tab delimited. I'm attempting to use CSVBeans version 0.7 to do this. In an XML configuration file, I have to pass a separator value to indicate how fields are delimited, as follows:

```
parser className="org.csvbeans.parsers.CSVParser"/>
    </strategy>
    <property name="separator" value="\t" />
    <property name="noStartTag" value="true" />
    <converters>
```

As shown above, I have tried `value="\t" />`, but it's not working. I have also tried `'\\t'` and `'\t'` but to no avail. What value should I use for a tab character?

folks it would be highly appreciated if you guys please let me know the solution specific to csv beans 0.7.1 jar .

Comment: Either try its code or `\\t`

Comment: I guess it's a XML question, not a Java question.

Comment: Note it is spelled 'delimited'.

Comment: @Shiju nops buddy it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean with "specific to csv beans"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML a tab character is represented as `&#009;`. So, your file should be like:

```xml
<parser className="org.csvbeans.parsers.CSVParser"/>
</strategy>
<property name="separator" value="&#009;" />
<property name="noStartTag" value="true" />
<converters>
```

Comment: Moritz . can you please let me know specific to csv beans 0.7

Comment: @user2288721 so you mean the configuration file is not correct? Based on the snippet it's hard to tell. Please check out the documentation of csvBeans.